# Call window function from electron

Tags: javascript, global-variables, electron, global, electron-packager

In one .js file I have

```
window.functionName = function(){

}
```

Now I want to call the function in the main electron file. How can I do that?

Here is what I tried to do in the main electron file:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow; 
var focusedWindow = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
focusedWindow.functionName();
```

It does not work. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getFocusedWindow` returns `BrowserWindow` object. `BrowserWindow` is electron's window object, not actual browser's global context - so none of `window.` global object is being exposed in BrowserWindow automatically. What you may need is get `webContents` via `focusedWindow.webContents` then ask renderer process to execute your javascript via `executeJavaScript` method. Main process and rendere process (browserWindow) are separate process, so you can't direcly invoke function right away but have to ask it.

Comment: How could I execute the function `functionName` in my case? Provide an example, please.

Comment: For anyone else with this issue, the way to do this is `mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript("functionName();");`. This function can also be used to call other JS operations in the browser window.